# How to create an API which has to query from a one to many relational table?

Tags: database, api

I have a database which has a `Folders` table and an `Images` table. Each image in the `Images` table belongs to one folder and is referenced by a foreign key. I am creating an API to retrieve all the folders and images within every folder. My API reponse should look something similar as this.

```
{
     'folder_name':'MyFolders',
     'folder_description':'Some description',
     'images': [{
                'name':'MyImage1',
                'description':'Some description'
     }]
}
```

Querying the images table and running a for loop against each image's `folder_id` to get the details of each folder would not be the most optimal solution. Is there a better way of solving this?

Comment: What about doing a left join and querying?

Answer (score 1):

As each image in the Images table belongs to one folder and is referenced by a foreign key , you need to have a join between Image and Folder Table . Your SQL query will be like this

**SELECT * FROM Image JOIN Folder ON Image.folderID = Folder.folderID**

This query will return all fields of Image Table and Folder Table